# Will tracking email opens increase spam score?

Tags: email, tracking, spam

I'm doing a small newsletter software for my business, and I'm wondering what metrics should I collect. Obviously, bounces and clicks should be tracked, but I'm wondering should I track email opens (via an image or a bgsound element)?

Do popular webmail services and ISPs check for tracking images and possibly increase my spam score? I guess if it increases the chances of ending up in a spam filter, I'd rather not collect that metric.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always it depends on the individual ISP and Webmail services.  However, I can share some anecdotal evidence: I periodically use mailchimp to send out mass email notifications, and email opens are tracked in mailchimp using the same approach you mentioned (See following link for reference: http://kb.mailchimp.com/reports/about-open-tracking).  I never experienced any issues with ending up in the spam folder, I have only had challenges with bounce backs and ending up in the Gmail promotions tab.

So based on the fact that some companies are already doing this, I have to say it probably won't increase your spam score.

Answer (score 3):

It's generally bad form to try to track your users in that way. Email opens are a private thing.

If you have an image with a unique URL per message, yes you can track it, but IMO, you really shouldn't. Including unnecessary images in an email is bad for a number of reasons:

1. Images can increase your spam score. There's a time and place for images. They can improve a message, but used inappropriately, they can look spammy.
2. It is obvious what you are doing. Sooner or later, one of your customers is likely to get wise to it. Some people won't care; others will feel violated.
3. It's REALLY unreliable. Most email clients and webmails feature an option to block images by default. You will get massively understated results.

Also remember, some people open an email immediately before they click the "delete" button. You are much better off tracking clicks.

There may be some merit in tracking the images you want to include anyway, but I'd not treat it as anything more than a very basic indicator.

Comment: You had no idea when he said image tracking.some of your points are correct though. let me explain you.  Placing an image for tracking not necessarily means a visual one which has some dimensions. In most of the cases softwares place 1X1 image for tracking purpose. people call this pixel tracking. Like you said not in all email clients images are opened by default. In some cases email clients might even strip out such images after finding out that it is not a valid one.

Comment: @KiranAmbati I recently came back to this answer, and totally agree with you. I've edited it.